# Yii: Calling Yii::app()->controller from Yii Console application

Tags: php, console, yii

I'm working in a Yii project which also have a console application.

Form the console app, I'm not calling any controller and working only on components which work fine but at someplaces, I need to call the variables / functions from Controller.php in components directory. That can be called for e.g.

```
Yii::app()->controller->aGlobalVariable;
```

But in console app, I'm not able to do that and it says:

`Trying to get property of non-object` ...

How do I make console app use it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In console you use CConsoleApplication which do not have controllers, you may use models of class inherited from CConsoleCommand

`yiic {your command} {your params for command}`

Ask Google: https://www.google.ru/search?q=yii+CConsoleCommand

> I need to call the variables / functions from Controller.php

You recode your vars and functions into stand alone class in \protected\components\, which you may call from controllers and consolecommand.

Comment: i'm already doing that but the thing is, the stuff in controller.php is being shared in web and console app. So i want to make use of the stuff in console app as well. Any alternate way to re use that code without writing more for console separately ?

Comment: Ya I think I need to move global variables in a component

Comment: U may call create your controller some likes this: Yii::import('app.controllers.MyController'); $myController = new MyController;

Comment: But this is not good - u have to set many hardcoded `stubs` (? sorry my english)

Comment: you are right, I've just move my global definitions to a new components. thanks for guiding.